# Would this be plural or singular?

Tags: plurals

In a sentence like 白と黒の犬がいます, would it be saying, "There is a black dog and a white dog," or, "There is one black and white dog"?

Answer (score 2):

「白と黒の犬がいます」 can be ambiguous and can be interpreted either as "There is a black dog and a white dog" or "There is one black and white dog".

If you want to more explicitly say "There is a black dog and a white dog", I think you could say 「白い犬と黒い犬がいます」 or 「白の犬と黒の犬がいます」, and for "There is one black and white dog", 「白黒の犬がいます」.